# How to protect the memory shared between processes in Linux

Tags: c, linux, memory

In Linux or other modern OS, each process's memory is protected, so that a wild write in one process does not crash any other process. Now assume we have memory shared between process A and process B. Now say, due to a soft error, process A unintentionally writes something to that memory area. Is there any way to protect against this, given that both process A and process B have full write access to that memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call [`shm_open`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open) you can pass it the `O_RDONLY` flag to the mode parameter.

Alternatively you can use [`mprotect`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mprotect) to mark specific pages as (e.g.) read-only. You'll need cooperation and trust between the two processes to do this, there is no way for B to say A can't write to it using `mprotect`.

If you really want to be sure that the other process can't interfere then communicating via pipes or sockets of some description might be a sensible idea.

You could also use `mmap` to map a something (e.g. in `/dev/shm`?) the file permissions make impossible to write to for one of the two processes if they're running as separate UIDs. For example if you have `/dev/shm/myprocess` owned by user producer and group consumer and set the file permissions to 0640 before mapping it by a process running with that UID and GID then you could prevent the second process from writing to it.

Comment: I know about mprotect, but as I said, both have full read and write access. It seems impossible to me to achieve this and I think reliability is one major issue of shared memory systems. isn't it?

Comment: @MetallicPriest updated to add the `O_RDONLY` flag for the open call. There are other solutions to this too though. I'll update again shortly.

Comment: Thanks awoodland. One solution that comes to my mind is to use a mutex for every access to the shared memory and give write access to the process only when it has locked the mutex. That will reduce chances of wild writes. However, I think this scheme would be very inefficient when frequency of shared memory access is high.

Comment: @MetallicPriest, if you have stray pointers, the mutex itself may be corrupted...

Comment: Changing permissions directly on "files" in `/dev/shm` is not portable. Instead you should specify the desired mode (permissions) when creating the shared memory object with `shm_open` and `O_CREAT`. Alternatively, just use a file in the normal filesystem instead of `shm_open` to get shared memory.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a simple checksum on each write. So, when a process detects wrong checksum upon a read operation, it's the sign of the failure of the other process.

Comment: You can use a checksum, but consider using a semaphore as well because checksum alone is going to be a horrible solution without some form of synchronization. But the best solution of you really want to be sure is to have a single master that write and reads that memory and communicate with it over a socket so it can validate each write.