# mprotect on a mmap-ed shared memory segment

Tags: c, memory, shared, mprotect

When two processes share a segment of memory opened with `shm_open` and then it gets `mmap`-ed, does doing an `mprotect` on a portion of the shared memory in one process affects the permissions seen by the other process **on this same portion**? In other words, if one process makes part of the shared memory segment read-only, does it become read-only for the other process too?

Comment: I have found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216870/how-to-protect-the-memory-shared-between-processes-in-linux/7216890#7216890, but still it would be worth if someone can provide a detailed reply.

Answer (score 2):

I always like to address those questions in two parts.

#### Part 1 - Let's test it

Let's consider an example that is relatively similar to the one at [`shm_open(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html).

Shared header - `shared.h`

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define errExit(msg) do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

struct shmbuf {
    char   buf[4096];
    sem_t  sem;
};
```

Creator process - `creator.c` (Compile using `gcc creator.c -o creator -lrt -lpthread`)

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "shared.h"

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s /shm-path\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *shmpath = argv[1];
    int fd = shm_open(shmpath, O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR,
                      S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (fd == -1)
        errExit("shm_open");

    struct shmbuf *shm;
    if (ftruncate(fd, sizeof(*shm)) == -1)
        errExit("ftruncate");

    shm = mmap(NULL, sizeof(*shm), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (shm == MAP_FAILED)
        errExit("mmap");

    if (sem_init(&shm->sem, 1, 0) == -1)
        errExit("sem_init");

    if (mprotect(&shm->buf, sizeof(shm->buf), PROT_READ) == -1)
        errExit("mprotect");

    if (sem_wait(&shm->sem) == -1)
        errExit("sem_wait");

    printf("got: %s\n", shm->buf);

    shm_unlink(shmpath);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Writer process - `writer.c` (Compile using `gcc writer.c -o writer -lrt -lpthread`)

```
#include <string.h>
#include "shared.h"

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s /shm-path string\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *shmpath = argv[1];
    char *string = argv[2];

    int fd = shm_open(shmpath, O_RDWR, 0);
    if (fd == -1)
        errExit("shm_open");

    struct shmbuf *shm = mmap(NULL, sizeof(*shm), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                              MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (shm == MAP_FAILED)
        errExit("mmap");

    strcpy(&shm->buf[0], string);

    if (sem_post(&shm->sem) == -1)
        errExit("sem_post");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

What's supposed to happen?
The creator process, creates a new shared memory object, "sets" its size, maps it into memory (as `shm`), uses `mprotect` to allow only writes to the buffer (`shm->buf`) and waits for a semaphore to know when the writer (which we will discuss in a moment finishes its thing).

The writer process starts, opens the same shared memory object, writes into it whatever we tell it to and signals the semaphore.

**Question is, will the writer be able to write to the shared memory object even though the creator changed the protection to READ-ONLY?**

Let's find out. We can run it using:

```
# ./creator.c /shmulik &
# ./writer.c /shmulik hi!
got: hi!
#
[1]+  Done                    ./creator /shmulik
```

As you can see, the writer was able to write to the shared memory, even though the creator set it's protection to READ-ONLY.

Maybe the creator does something wrong? Let's try to add the following line to `creator.c`:

```
    if (mprotect(&shm->buf, sizeof(shm->buf), PROT_READ) == -1)
        errExit("mprotect");

    memset(&shm->buf, 0, sizeof(shm->buf)); // <-- This is the new line

    if (sem_wait(&shm->sem) == -1)
        errExit("sem_wait");
```

Let's recompile & run the creator again:

```
# gcc creator.c -o creator -lrt -lpthread
# ./creator /shmulik
Segmentation fault
```

As you can see, the `mprotect` worked as expected.

How about we let the writer map the shared memory, then we change the protection? Well, it ain't going to change anything. `mprotect` ONLY affects the memory protection of the process calling it (and it's descendants).

#### Part 2 - Let's understand it

First, you have to understand that `shm_open` is a glibc method, it's not a systemcall.
You can get the `glibc` source code from [their website](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/sources.html) and just look for `shm_open` to see that yourself.

The underlying implementation of `shm_open` is a regular call for `open`, just like the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) suggests.

As we already saw, most of the magic happens in `mmap`. When calling `mmap`, we have to use `MAP_SHARED` (rather than `MAP_PRIVATE`), otherwise every process is going to get a private memory segment to begin with, and obviously one ain't gonna affect the other.

When we call `mmap`, the hops are roughly:

- [ksys_mmap_pgoff](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18/source/mm/mmap.c#L1590).
- [vm_mmap_pgoff](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18/source/mm/util.c#L506).
- [do_mmap](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18/source/mm/mmap.c#L1411)
- [mmap_region](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18/source/mm/mmap.c#L1720)

At that last point, you could see that we take the process' memory management context `mm` and allocate a new virtual memory area `vma`:

```
struct mm_struct *mm = current->mm;
...
vma = vm_area_alloc(mm);
...
vma->vm_page_prot = vm_get_page_prot(vm_flags);
```

This memory area is not shared with other processes.
Since `mprotect` changes only the `vm_page_prot` on the per-process `vma`, it doesn't affect other processes that map the same memory space.

Answer (score 1):

The POSIX specification for [`mprotect()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mprotect.html) suggests that changes in the protection of shared memory should affect all processes using that shared memory.

Two of the error conditions detailed are:

- [EAGAIN]
  The `prot` argument specifies PROT_WRITE over a MAP_PRIVATE mapping and there are insufficient memory resources to reserve for locking the private page.
- [ENOMEM]
  The `prot` argument specifies PROT_WRITE on a MAP_PRIVATE mapping, and it would require more space than the system is able to supply for locking the private pages, if required.

These strongly suggest that memory that is mapped with MAP_SHARED should not fail because of a lack of memory for making copies.

See also the POSIX specification for [`mmap()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Both of the answers are amazing, but I found the one by Daniel a bit more detailed and interesting to follow for unexperienced users like me. Regardless, I insist, thank you, Jonathan.

Comment: Given a choice between the two answers, I’d accept the other too.